# Can't deploy external app to jetty 9.0.6.v20130930

Tags: jetty

When I'm deploying my app by copying it inside jetty/webapps it deploys ok. But I want to deploy it from external directory. For that I've created following  myconf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="myapp" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="server">
        <Ref refid="Server" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="myapp.war" /><!-- points to the external war -->
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Then jetty is ran with:

java  -XX:-UseSplitVerifier  -jar start.jar myconf.xml.

In the console I see that application is being deployed, it accesses db etc, but when I try to reach it I got 404. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use Jetty.

**Option 1: Standard Automatic Deployment**

1. Since you are not customizing anything with the deployment, just delete the `myconf.xml` entirely.
2. Copy your `myapp.war` into the `${jetty.home}/webapps/` directory.
3. Start Jetty.  `$ java -jar start.jar`

This is known as [Automatic Web Application Deployment](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.5.v20130815/automatic-webapp-deployment.html).

**Option 2: Standard Context Deployment**

Now, if you want to customize the deployment, (say for example you want to tweak the context path it listens on, or if you want to disable the extractWar process, or you have custom init parameters, or you even want to change the behavior of the Default servlet, etc...), then do the following ...

1. Copy your existing `myconf.xml` to `${jetty.home}/webapps/myapp.xml` (note the name change)
2. Copy your `myapp.war` to `${jetty.home}/webapps/myapp.war` (note, the basename for this file should be the same as your XML)
3. Edit your `${jetty.home}/webapps/myapp.xml` to change the deployment behavior (eg: `<Set name="contextPath">/app/1</Set>`)
4. Start Jetty. `$ java -jar start.jar`

This is known as [Configuring Specific WebApp Deployment](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.5.v20130815/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html).

**Option 3: Customized Context Deployment**

If you want to keep your war file somewhere other than `${jetty.home}/webapps/`, you will still need to do the following:

1. Copy your existing `myconf.xml` to to `${jetty.home}/webapps/myconf.xml`.
2. Leave your `myapp.war` where you want it.  For example `/opt/webapps/myapp.war`
3. Edit your `${jetty.home}/webapps/myconf.xml` to set the `contextPath` and `war` entries.
4. Start Jetty. `$ java -jar start.jar`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="myapp" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="server">
        <Ref refid="Server" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="/opt/webapps/myapp.war" />
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

**Option 4: Jetty Base Automatic Deployment (Available in Jetty 9.1+)**

There is another technique, available starting with Jetty 9.1, using the split `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` concepts + the Automatic Deployment from above.

Lets say you have jetty-distribution-9.1.x unpacked into `/opt/jetty/` and you have your webapp + configuration in `/opt/myapps/`.  You can do the following commands.

```
[user]$ cd /opt/myapps

[myapps]$ java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --add-to-start=server,deploy,websocket,ext,resources
server          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
deploy          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
deploy          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/webapps
server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
websocket       initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
websocket       enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
server          enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
ext             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
ext             enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib/ext
resources       initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini (appended)
resources       enabled in     ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/resources

[myapps]$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 user group 4096 Oct 31 08:32 lib/
drwxrwxr-x 2 user group 4096 Oct 31 08:32 resources/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  369 Oct 31 08:30 start.ini
drwxrwxr-x 2 user group 4096 Oct 31 08:30 webapps/

[myapps]$ cat start.ini
--module=server
threads.min=10
threads.max=200
threads.timeout=60000
jetty.dump.start=false
jetty.dump.stop=false

--module=deploy
--module=websocket
--module=ext
--module=resources

[myapps]$ java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --list-config | grep -E "jetty.(base|home)="
 jetty.home=/opt/jetty
 jetty.base=/opt/myapps

[myapps]$ cp /home/user/project/myapp/target/myapp-1.0.war /opt/myapps/webapps/myapp.war

[myapps]$ java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar
2013-10-31 08:35:58.919:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.0.RC0
2013-10-31 08:35:58.939:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/myapps/webapps/] at interval 1
2013-10-31 08:35:59.109:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /myapp, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2013-10-31 08:35:59.189:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@223ff173{/myapp,file:/tmp/jetty-myapp.war-_myapp-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/myapp.war}
```

What you'll notice is that you have 2 locations you can work with.

- `${jetty.home}` - where your jetty-distribution is located
- `${jetty.base}` - where your app's specific configuration and wars are located

This is a pretty powerful option, and I've only touched the surface of its capabilities.

Comment: Are you sure I can't avoid copying war to  ${jetty.home}/webapps/? What's the purpose of the WebAppContext's war property then? And event the link you gave (Configuring Specific WebApp Deployment) implies external war location (/opt/myapp/myapp.war)

Comment: Update the answer for your extra question.